# How to load javascript files in Windows phone 8 application?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 application, i am using WebBrowser control in a page. When user clicks on a button, i am navigate a .html file onto the webBrowser. The html is calling some css and js files in head section.Css files are loading perfectly but js files are not working. Can anyone please help me by giving their views on how js files will work?

My XAML code:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Games_WebBrowser" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Code behind:

```
private void LeftNavCategories_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
       Games_WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("/index.html", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Head section of .html file

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/bind_polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/classlist_polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/animframe_polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="js/keyboard_input_manager.js"></script>
  <script src="js/html_actuator.js"></script>
  <script src="js/grid.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tile.js"></script>
  <script src="js/local_storage_manager.js"></script>
  <script src="js/game_manager.js"></script>
  <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer i found to my question.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Games_WebBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

I Got my answer by adding a simple tag IsScriptEnabled="True" by default it is false we need to make it true.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a windows phone developer, but I have done several Windows 8 apps and I have had issues with them too. Most often this are problems with the same origin policy. This is what helped me mostly:

1. Try to add a slash before the src `<script src="/js/game_manager.js"></script>`
2. Try to add a `file://`
3. Add a `ms-appx://` ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx))
4. Some function-calls are marked as `insecure`. For example `innerHtml()`. Try out if this could be an Issue by adding a `alert("test")` to your first js-file. If this output is show, you don't have a problem with loading the files. Instead there are problems with the code itself. Try to test innerHtml than.

If all this does not help, try to make a Javascript Project instead of a XAML Project